# Select menu background goes black on IE for angular material md-select

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-material

There is one issue with the angular material with IE-11 and IE-edge browsers,

When the body content is vertically scrolling then angular meterial show the black border around the select box as shown in this image. 
[image]

Here is also the code pen where the issue is reproduced.

`<md-input-container>
        <label>State</label>
        <md-select ng-model="ctrl.userState">
          <md-option ng-repeat="state in ctrl.states" value="{{state.abbrev}}" ng-disabled="$index === 1">
            {{state.abbrev}}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzRjBx

Issue can be solved by removing the `position:fixed`. but it will create issue with the angular material functionality.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

none of the other answers I posted earlier seem to be a perfect fit although they initially seemed to resolve the issue.

The real culprit seems to be the background set by angular-material.

See the following codepen for the fix:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwOdNm

The following style causes this issue:

```
html.md-default-theme, html, body.md-default-theme, body {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
}
```

overriding with the following style seems to be completely fixed the issue:

```
html.md-default-theme, html, body.md-default-theme, body {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  You should mark it as the answer for any other that are having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to happen when bootstrap is also used along with angular material. haven't found a fix yet.

Comment: it seem this is not the actual issue. please see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to happen when bootstrap is also used along with angular material.

the culprit seems to be border-box sizing on *.

md-select (displays weird backgrounds) when border-box is used on *

e.g. * { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

Therefore, using bootstrap along with angular-material causes this issue.

The following fixes it but screws up bootstrap styling. * { -webkit-box-sizing: unset; -moz-box-sizing: unset; box-sizing: unset; }

Comment: it seem this is not the actual issue. please see my other answer.